# Is TCP 100% reliable?

Tags: c, linux, tcp

Although TCP is a reliable protocol which provides retransmission and acknowledgement mechanisms but I believe its not 100% reliable since the successful return of send() doesn't ensure that the data has reached the destination endpoint and only means that the data is copied to the kernel buffer.

Is there any mechanism for the application to know whether data has reached successfully to the destination?

One possible solution could be to have some acknowledgement mechanism build up into the application layer?

Comment: Indeed, build an acknowledgement mechanism into your application layer if you cannot trust your platform's implementation of TCP.

Comment: And then, is the acknowledgment mechanism 100% reliable?

Comment: It's not possible to make any protocol 100% reliable. See [Two Generals Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem)

Comment: @Barmar only if reliability needs to be two-way. A simple acknowledgement suffices to know that the message was received (guessing we are not worried by MITM attacks in this particular scenario).

Comment: @tucuxi: in that case there are false negatives (where you don't receive the acknowledgement, but the message in fact was received). Whether that's sufficient to count as 100% reliability really depends on the application: often it's OK to have only one side that re-sends until acknowledged, and that's basically what TCP does under the covers to provide its guarantees.

Comment: @Jessop true; but my comment still remains true: *if* you receive the acknowledgement, *then* the message was correctly received at the other side. (If you do *not* receive it, you are right that you will never know what happened; the safest bet is to assume that it was simply lost to the ether.)

Answer (score 4):

TCP is reliable in the sense that messages sent will either

1. be received as they were sent (same order, same contents); assuming that the built-in checksum does not happen to fail, which it may, since it is only 16 bits **OR**
2. not be received at all

Using TCP, messages received should never be out-of-order or missing intermediate messages.

To distinguish cases 1 and 2, you should implement an acknowledgement mechanism. A good idea that would also ensure better-than-CRC message integrity is to send back an MD5 or other hash of the incoming message.

Comment: TCP uses checksum, not CRC.

Comment: @Barmar CRC _is_ a checksum!

Comment: CRC is more than just a checksum, it uses bit shifting to protect against reordering, which checksum doesn't detect.

Comment: ok, I meant checksum. Editing...

Comment: @Barmar indeed, CRC16 et al use that, but CRC does actually stand for "Cyclic Redundancy _Checksum_".

Comment: No, it stands for [Cyclic Redundancy Check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own app, reply success message to sender by receiver and re-send as needed if no success message received.

In Java, JMS do this work, I believe there should some existing library do the same in C.

Answer (score -2):

Of course TCP is the reliable protocol , if you wanna know data which is delivered and received through the network port use wireshark software  to capture the data which is transmitted and received  . Through wireshark you can trace out the packets.

Comment: how is using wireshark remotely going to help an _application_ know whether its transmissions were received?!

Comment: Please see how to use wireshark you can capture the packets which are going away from your machine and packets which are coming into your machine

Comment: you're missing the point.  Of course you can use wireshark to perform "third party" analysis of a traffic flow.   What you can't use it for is to tell a particular application whether its own packets have been received.